# kCGImagePropertyOrientation incompatible pointer

Tags: ios, core-image

I'm implementing Auto Enhancing in my app. My code goes like this:

```
CIImage *toBeEnhancedImage = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:_originalImage.CGImage];

NSDictionary *options = @{CIDetectorImageOrientation : [[toBeEnhancedImage properties] valueForKey:kCGImagePropertyOrientation]};

NSArray *adjustments = [toBeEnhancedImage autoAdjustmentFiltersWithOptions:options];
```

Before Running the code, I get the following error next to NSDictionary:

> Incompatible pointer types sending 'const CFStringRef (AKA 'const struct__CFString *const*)to parameter of type NSString*

When i run the code, it crashes. I know what the error means but the code is actually taken from Apple's documentation and it doesn't work! is there a workaround?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should type cast your `CFStringRef` variable to `NSString *`. Change the second line of your code with below lines:

```
NSDictionary *options = nil;
if([[toBeEnhancedImage properties] valueForKey:(NSString *)kCGImagePropertyOrientation] == nil)
{
    options = @{CIDetectorImageOrientation : [NSNumber numberWithInt:1]};
}
else
{
   options = @{CIDetectorImageOrientation : [[toBeEnhancedImage properties] valueForKey:(NSString *)kCGImagePropertyOrientation]};
}
```

Comment: made the change and the app still crashes at the same line although it shows no alert in yellow.

Comment: What is the console log? I think you are trying to insert nil value inside the dictionary.

Comment: okay here is what is showing:
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x2d953f4b 0x380c26af 0x2d89217b 0x2d891f43 0xe046b 0x300cb37b 0x300cb139 0x302573eb 0x30175273 0x3017507d 0x30175015 0x300c6da3 0x2fd4dc6b 0x2fd4947b 0x2fd4930d 0x2fd48d1f 0x2fd48b2f 0x2d91ceb3 0x2d887c27 0x2d887a0b 0x3257b283 0x3012b049 0x10e98d 0x385caab7)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: No. Your image is not having the orientation property. So you are trying to insert NULL in dictionary. The default value of this property is NSNumber with value 1. So, we change it accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, worked like a silk! It is amazing how crappy is the code published by Apple. I am convinced, 100%, that they hate dealing with developers. Writing a decent doc is something that we will never see.